# Sharing Gemfile.lock across both windows and linux environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I've been advised not to untrack Gemfile.lock, however i ran into issues.

I develop on my windows machine, and push to a linux (ubuntu) server, the issue is Bundler locks the windows version of some gems, by adding: `x86-mingw32` after the version number, which causes issues.

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.1)
    ...
    mysql2 (0.3.11-x86-mingw32)
    ...

  PLATFORMS
    x86-mingw32
```

I use Capistrano to deploy, and i get this error:

**Please install the mysql adapter: gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)**

Even though my gemfile is like:

```
...
gem 'mysql2'
...
```

I think that's because Rails tries to use the windows version of mysql2 which is found on Gemfile.lock

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add something like the following to your Gemfile and then bundle update
(Replace your current mysql2 gem listing obviously)

```
  
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32/
  gem "mysql2", :platform => [:mswin, :mingw]
else
  gem "mysql2", :platform => :ruby
end
```

What this means is if the platform is 'win32' (Windows) then install the windows version, else install the normal version which is 'ruby' for all Unix systems. At least I don't know any Unix systems (from Mac OS X, to Linux, to Solaris, to *BSD) that that wouldn't work on.

UPDATE: Got a bit more information. The problem is that --deployment flag *only* looks at the lock file. Otherwise you could forgo the --deployment, lock your gems to a specific version in the Gemfile itself, and then run a bundle update to force the Gemfile to be re-evaluated which would force the selector. The problem is that bundle is not capable of what you want *because* it only evaluates the lock file when using --deployment flag. This means it has no way to re-evaluate what platform its on. It goes *strictly* by what is in the lock file. This is why the only real solution is to lock your gem versions in the main Gemfile, and then bundle update to force the re-eval.

You could probably forgo the --deployment and just use

```
  
    bundle update && bundle install --without=development,test,any_other_groups --path=./vendor/bundle
```

This is a necessity if you're going to be developing on a completely different platform than what you're deploying on due to, as referenced, the way bundler works. The above command should replicate exactly what --deployment does. All of this will be recorded in .bundle/config as well.

Comment: Thanks for the Info! Is there a way to disable `--deployment` while still using the helpers from `bundler/capistrano`

Comment: That I can't tell you. I don't use capistrano personally.

Comment: Thanks, I got it figured out with the line above :)

Comment: this looks promising, as soon as i get home i will try this, if it works you are a life saver !

Answer (score 1):

You can check the RUBY_PLATFORM by typing this at the command prompt on Windows.

```
ruby -e 'puts RUBY_PLATFORM'
```

For example, this Gemfile can be shared on my Windows laptop and Linux sever.

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /(win32)|(i386-mingw32)/
  gem 'mongrel','1.2.0.pre2'
else
  gem 'unicorn'
end
```